# Python Google Drive API : uploaded image is shown inside a doc

Tags: python-2.7, google-drive-api

I am using the below code to upload an image to google drive from my python app:

```
import logging

from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
import httplib2

from gdoauth2.models import DriveCredential



class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        credential = DriveCredential.objects.latest('id').credential
        http = credential.authorize(httplib2.Http())
        service = build('drive', 'v2', http=http)
        mime_type = 'image/jpg'
        filename = '/<path>/test.jpg'
        logging.info('uploading %s' % filename)
        media_body = MediaFileUpload(
            filename, mimetype=mime_type, resumable=True)
        upload = service.files().insert(
            body=dict(title='test.jpg', mimeType=mime_type),
            media_body=media_body, convert=True).execute()
```

After uploading i can see the image as being inserted to a doc file with name 'test.jpg' instead of viewing it as an exact image file in my google drive. How can I upload an image as an exact image file in google drive. Also please help me to upload an image from a url.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change the last line to:

```
upload = service.files().insert(
        body=dict(title='test.jpg', mimeType=mime_type),
        media_body=media_body, convert=False).execute()
```

convert=True will perform OCR on the image and save the image and OCR text to a Google Doc. It sounds like that's not what you want.

Comment: Yes, it worked!!! Thanks Jay Lee, Can you please help me on how to upload image from a url (eg:http://www.example.com/example.jpg) to google drive...